# Trouble with Shapefiles / BlenderGIS

Tags: modeling, import

I have a hopefully simple question for you: I'm using BlenderGIS to import shapefiles. I have a shapefile of the state of California and a second shapefile of a subregion of it. They are both in the same geocoordinate format (EPSG:4326) and when I open them in QGIS they open (nearly) completely correctly - same dimensions and correct location.

Unfortunately, when I import them using BlenderGIS, this is no longer true: the California shapefile is enormous, and the subregion shapefile is tiny. Despite futzing with the settings per this other answer https://speckle.community/t/blender-to-qgis-georeferencing-not-working/5699/13, nothing changes it. Even more annoying, the geolocation seems to make absolutely no difference to where the items show up in general - i.e. if I use the basemap approach as outlined here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WviTi0q2BpA&t=4s, then the new shapefiles do not in any way correspond to the underlying map coordinates. They just show up randomly.

What I want is a consistent way to ensure that when I import Shapefiles using the same CSR and regions, they import and overlap with the correct dimensions, proportions, and coordinates (i.e. half of the point of shapefiles).

I'm even less of an expert on GIS / Shapefiles than I am on Blender, so I hope I'm just missing something easy and obvious. Thanks for your help!